# Undefined class constant 'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::HOME'

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-6, laravel-authentication, laravel-upgrade

After upgrading the laravel 5.8 to laravel 6.x I am getting this error:

```
Undefined class constant 'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::HOME'
```

Before upgrading the application login system was the custom. After upgrading to laravel 6.x I want to use laravel default authentication. I created authentication through `php artisan ui:auth` and I copied controllers from fresh laravel `app/Http/Controllers/Auth` folder with auth related controllers like - `LoginController`, `RegisterController` etc.

What should I do to solve the above error? Would someone help me, please?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In Laravel 6 the `$redirectTo` property in the auth controllers was updated so that it was easier to change across the board. [Link to PR](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/5173).

To fix the error you can either add the following to your `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php` class:

```
/**
 * The path to the "home" route for your application.
 *
 * @var string
 */
public const HOME = '/home';
```

or in each of your auth controller update the `$redirectTo` property to be the route that you want to use:

```
protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
```

becomes

```
protected $redirectTo = '/the-path-you-want-to-redirect-to';
```

Answer (score 3):

in my case:

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
    public const HOME = '/home';
```

just add this line

```
public const HOME = '/home';
```

as Laravel documents  said https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#included-authenticating

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue, I found that it's not the same constant
in the RouteServiceProvider class, you will find Home not HOME. I think this issue came with LARAVEL because my project is new.

my LARAVEL version is 7.7.0

Answer (score -1):

in my case i've changed the word `HOME`in `protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;`into lowercase `home` like that `protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::home;` that what caused me the error above, so i've just put it again in uppercase and now it's Ok !